# How to control text position of <ul> <li>?

Tags: html, css

While working with `<ul>` `<li>` tag, I've encountered basic issue.

Here is the screenshot causing problem.
[image]

Here is the ideal format I want.
[image]

I think I can just control this by using `<li>` tag CSS property.

Comment: It would be best to provide us with the concrete code example so we are able to help you directly on that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of including your tag in each `li`, you can [set the bullet style](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp) with `list-style-type`. Setting the value `lower-alpha` will bullet your list items with lowercase letters. Since the bullets are being styled, the lines will maintain their original wrapping and indentation styles.

```css
.ul-alpha li {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla, sem in maximus fringilla, metus lorem fringilla diam, in gravida.</li>
  <li>b. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla, sem in maximus fringilla, metus lorem fringilla diam, in gravida.</li>
  <li>c. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla, sem in maximus fringilla, metus lorem fringilla diam, in gravida.</li>
  <li>d. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla, sem in maximus fringilla, metus lorem fringilla diam, in gravida.</li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul-alpha">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla, sem in maximus fringilla, metus lorem fringilla diam, in gravida.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla, sem in maximus fringilla, metus lorem fringilla diam, in gravida.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla, sem in maximus fringilla, metus lorem fringilla diam, in gravida.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla, sem in maximus fringilla, metus lorem fringilla diam, in gravida.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `list-style-position: inside;` you might need to play with the `padding-left` value.

*I also used `<ol>` instead of `<ul>` here as in your example you have an ordered list*

```css
ol {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.list-1 {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.list-2 {
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="list-1">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
</ol>

<ol class="list-2">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</li>
</ol>
```